# C func dynamically allocates mem for arbitrarily long line; passes unit testing, crashes in situ

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function, `dgets`, the sole purpose of which is to take in a string of arbitrary length from `stdin`.  Here's the full text of the file I use for unit testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dgets(char** lnptr, int lastIndex)
/*
   RETRIEVE A LINE OF ARBITRARY LENGTH FROM STDIN
*/
{
   char c;
   int i = 0;

   while( (c = getchar()) && c != EOF && c != '\n' ) { 
      if( i >= lastIndex-1 ) { 
         lastIndex *= 2;
         *lnptr = (char*)realloc(*lnptr, lastIndex);
      }   

      *(*lnptr + i) = c;
      ++i;
   }   

   if( c == '\n' ) { 
      *(*lnptr + i) = c;
      *lnptr = (char*)realloc(*lnptr, i+1);
      *(*lnptr + i+1) = '\0';
   }   

   return i;
}

int main()
{
        char* line;

        line = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char));

        while( dgets(&line, 10)) {
                printf("****************\n%s****************\n", line);
                free(line);
                line = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This program performs exactly as expected, with exactly zero errors or bugs.  That's nice, because I want to use it in a larger program.  After copying and pasting the code for `dgets` into the larger program, and after a successful compile with `-Wall` (1 warning, no errors reported by gcc), running the larger program results in `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Examining the corefile with gdb produces this:

```
$ coredumpctl gdb 14527
          PID: 14527 (a.out)
          UID: 1000 (demiurge)
          GID: 1000 (demiurge)
       Signal: 11 (SEGV)
    Timestamp: Wed 2015-08-05 15:48:28 CDT (1min 58s ago)
 Command Line: ./a.out
   Executable: /home/demiurge/learning_c/KR_exercises/chapter_1/a.out
Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c1.scope
         Unit: session-c1.scope
        Slice: user-1000.slice
      Session: c1
    Owner UID: 1000 (demiurge)
      Boot ID: 629b0a58691c4ec488bd0b84276df9d4
   Machine ID: 4c9566d65e864c6da8e41bfaf8ed2cb4
     Hostname: exmachina
     Coredump: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.a\x2eout.1000.629b0a58691c4ec488bd0b84276df9d4.14527.1438807708000000.lz4
      Message: Process 14527 (a.out) of user 1000 dumped core.

Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f253e36cd80 in _int_realloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f253e36cd80 in _int_realloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f253e36e0f0 in realloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400753 in dgets (lnptr=0x7ffeaf001050, lastIndex=40) at ./1.13.c:41
#3  0x00000000004009a2 in main () at ./1.13.c:107
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x00000000004009a2 in main () at ./1.13.c:107
107     while( dgets(&line, SIZE) ) {
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000000000400753 in dgets (lnptr=0x7ffeaf001050, lastIndex=40) at ./1.13.c:41
41              *lnptr = (char*)realloc(*lnptr, lastIndex);
```

Further examination with gdb confirms that the segfault occurs at the second iteration of the first call to `realloc` in `dgets`. So my question is this: *Why is `realloc` triggering a segfault after `dgets` passes unit testing?*

Help me to understand, oh merciful and beneficent StackOverlords!

**ADDENDUM:**

Okay, so here's the code that runs just before `dgets` is called:

```
int main()
{
        char* line;
        int* lengths;
        int longest;

        line = (char*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
        lengths = (int*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));

        //get a line from stdin
        while( dgets(&line, SIZE) ) { 

                //count how many words are of length n
                longest = countWordLengths(line, &lengths);

                //do a little housekeeping
                free((void*)line);
                line = (char*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
                if( line == NULL ) { return 1; }
        }

        .
        .some other stuff happens here, but the code never gets this far.
        .
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Valgrind?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I haven't. Today is the first I've ever heard of Valgrind; I'm beginning to suspect that it's about to become a new and shiny favorite toy of mine.

Comment: Note that you're only NUL-terminating when input ended with a new-line, not for any of the other `while` condition conjuncts (`EOF` for example). Also: `*(*lineptr + i)` == `(*lineptr)[i]`, but the latter is more readable.

Comment: But FWIW, it's possible that the bug isn't in this code at all.  Maybe in your "in situ" code you already corrupted the heap, or are passing an invalid pointer as an arg, or something.  Without a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: You should *really* check the return value of `calloc()` and `realloc()` for `NULL`. Also, if `realloc()` returns `NULL`, you leak memory. Furthermore, `EOF` is an `int`, not a `char`, so if you want to check `c` against `EOF`, you damn well better define it as `int c`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I'm about to add the `main` from the program that doesn't work.  I'd be curious to see if I'm corrupting the heap prior to my call to `dgets`.  @EOF, thanks for the safety advice.  And correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the C spec. define `char`s as very small `int`s?

Comment: Yes, `char` is an integer type. However, `char` generally does not have the range to hold all integer values an `int` will hold. `EOF` is an `int`, `getchar()` returns an `int`, do you see where this is going? Also: `*lnptr = (char*)realloc(*lnptr, i+1);
      *(*lnptr + i+1) = '\0';` is wrong. You `realloc()` to a size of `i+1` and then try to access the `i+1`th element, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Typically `EOF` is in the range of `char`, but the result of `getchar` may not be!   The key point is that there are `UCHAR_MAX+2` possible results of `getchar`, therefore `char` cannot hold them all.

Comment: @EOF your last comment could be posted as the answer

Comment: @EOF *lnptr = (char*)realloc(*lnptr, i+2); *(*lnptr + i+1) = '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is for all of my fellow newbies who are getting error messages that say something about malloc/realloc/calloc and invalid new/old addresses, in addition to segmentation faults:

**[Get and use Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).**  It's a free and open source heap profiler that will show you where in your code heap corruption(s) are manifesting, which will in turn provide some insights into where and how those heap corruptions are occuring.

In this particular case I had multiple heap corruptions occuring throughout my code, largely because of an impropoper argument passed to `realloc`. What I wanted to do was resize a block of memory that would hold integers, like so:

`*lnptr = (int*) realloc (*lnptr, newSize * sizeof(int));`

But what I had originally written was this:

`*lnptr = (int*) realloc (*lnptr, newSize);`

See that second parameter in `realloc`?  The problem this was causing is that `*lnptr` was ending up being only `newSize` bytes wide, which is fine if I only needed to store `newSize char`s and terrible if I want to store `newSize int`s.

Lesson learned; read the friendly manual closely. And, use Valgrind if you're going to be dynamically allocating memory.